# MySQL Filter result where columns = '$'

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am trying to filter rows where column = '$'

here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE currency_symbol = "$"
```

but it returns empty row set
even table has many rows with $ symbol

Comment: show us some examples on the table and maybe setup a sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try like keyword in where clause

```
 WHERE currency_symbol like  '%$%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE currency_symbol = '$'

or 

SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE currency_symbol like  '%$%'
```